# Can the compiler reduce these recursive copy/move examples? (C++17-C++20)

Tags: c++, recursion, optimization, c++17, move-semantics

This is not about the runtime efficiency of a program, profiling and so on. What I want to know is what expressions can be reduced at compile time, should be, or will be as a guarantee. But it's an extremely tricky subject, it depends on optimization level, and I'm sure it's finicky even when you know what you're doing. I mainly want to know if I'm on the right track. So I wrote up a couple of examples on copy/move semantics.

First, is this function...

```
template<std::size_t I, class S, class... T>
decltype(auto) nth(S && s, T &&... t) noexcept {
    if constexpr(I == 0) return std::forward<S>(s);
    else return f<I-1>(std::forward<T>(t)...);
}
```

Then is `nth<2>(w, x, y, z);` the exact same cost as `std::forward<Y>(y)`? I believe it should be, because the static conditional should either quit early and return a single call to `std::forward`, or it should recurse until it can do so, each time just discarding an argument and referring to the rest where they were. Then the tail is discarded at the end anyway. I'm betting that it can see through recursion like that, especially since it already computes the return type up front, and can telescope it down to a single `std::forward<Y>(y)`. But maybe I'm giving it too much credit.

Here's another:

```
template<class L, class... R>
decltype(auto) last(L && l, R &&... r) noexcept
  { return (std::forward<L>(l) ,..., std::forward<R>(r)); }
```

The fold expression is supposed to emulate individual binary functions, so I'm a little wary of this one. At the same time, the binary in question just discards the left argument, so the next left hand side to be discarded is the forwarded right side of the previous. If the result of `std::forward<L>(l)` is going to be discarded, is it still evaluated to any cost? It goes through a number of recursions before being discarded. I know there's a recursion limit, after which point maybe the compiler won't optimize the function or maybe it just won't compile it at all. But before that, I want to know what happens to the function.

I also assume at each level of recursion, a function is instantiated, but in name only. So, another context can use the name in a pointer, etc. Only the endpoints should matter when all you do is relabel references. But if I'm right, if all you do is point to the function, naming it won't interrupt any reduction that eliminates it elsewhere.

In case this comes across as premature optimization, it's also not about squeezing a drop of performance out of a passthrough function, or about reinventing `std::get`, etc. This is tied to the fundamentals of the language and I hate a shaky foundation. So thanks for your help, I've had these questions on the back of my mind for a while.

Comment: Because your return types are `auto` (and not `decltype(auto)`) none of your function calls can guarantee the exact same cost as `std::forward<Y>(y)`.  You are copying the object.

Comment: Good catch, I think I used `decltype(auto)` in my code. Did you notice anything else?

Comment: I know enough about C++ compilers to know that the optimizer will _almost always_ do a better job than I would.  You can assume that these functions will be collapsed to their simplest forms, but you can almost _never_ be **guaranteed** any particular optimization.